# Placing information inside the chart series

Tags: echarts

I have the chart bellow and I want to add the percentage to the series body. Like I manipulate the image bellow in red.

how Is this possible?
https://codesandbox.io/s/label-line-adjust-forked-09ukre?file=/index.js

```js
var dom = document.getElementById("chart-container");
var myChart = echarts.init(dom, null, {
  renderer: "canvas",
  useDirtyRect: false
});
var app = {};

var option;

var datas = [
  ////////////////////////////////////////
  [
    { name: "test1", value: 20 },
    { name: "test2", value: 40 },
    { name: "test3", value: 40 }
  ]
];
option = {
  title: {
    text: "test",
    left: "center",
    textStyle: {
      color: "#999",
      fontWeight: "normal",
      fontSize: 14
    }
  },
  series: datas.map(function (data, idx) {
    return {
      type: "pie",
      radius: [80, 160],
      top: "10%",
      height: "33.33%",
      left: "center",
      width: 400,
      itemStyle: {
        borderColor: "#fff",
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      label: {
        alignTo: "edge",
        minMargin: 5,
        edgeDistance: 10,
        lineHeight: 15,
        rich: {
          time: {
            fontSize: 10,
            color: "#999"
          }
        }
      },
      labelLine: {
        length: 15,
        length2: 0,
        maxSurfaceAngle: 80
      },

      data: data
    };
  })
};

if (option && typeof option === "object") {
  myChart.setOption(option);
}

window.addEventListener("resize", myChart.resize);
```

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To place information inside the chart, you have to use `position: "inside"` in the [label](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-pie.label). Set what is put inside the label with the [formatter](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-pie.label.formatter). (Here, {c} is the value of a data item)

```js
label: {
   formatter: "{c}%",
   position: "inside"
},
```

[image]

But it seems that it's not possible to have both a label inside AND one outside the same chart (like in your image). However, a workaround can do the job here. Like using 2 identical series except one has the label from your example code, and one has the label code I wrote above. One chart will be on top of the other (wich is a bit messy) but the result will be as you want :

[image]